# Azure DevOps: Is it possible to remove inherited policies from project level, for a specific repository?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a Project in Azure DevOps with 3 branch policies for master development and features, I need to bypass the master policy for specific repositories to change groups to approve PRs.
Is there a way to disable the inherited policy and add custom groups to approve the PRs?

Azure DevOps has no info about this topic.

Comment: Hi, please read [MS document Bypass branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#bypass-branch-policies) to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set bypass branch policies permissions for you, so then you can bypass it to complete PRs or even push code directly to the branch.

Also, any policies you configure at the branch level will overwrite the policies inherited at project/repository level.

More info here

https://elanderson.net/2020/05/azure-devops-repos-bypass-branch-policies/